ns3-leo in lastest version of ns3
I want to use ns3-leo for my research. I have tried using it in the latest version of NS-3, but it hasn't worked, even after attempting to change the wscript to CMakeLists.txt.
My question is: Is there a solution for integrating ns3-leo with the latest version of NS-3, or should I revert to using an older version?
am installing NS3-LEO IN NS-3.40 and would appreciate some guidance on the installation process.
